# combine functions in ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I have a function which takes two arguments, I want to curry it because it used more that one time in code. here is the function :

```
const discount = R.sum(R.map(R.propOr('0', 'discount'), invoiceArr));
```

now I want to give argument's ('`discount`' & `invoiceArr`) and return the value.
I have try another way which like below:

```
const sumByPropName = R.curryN(2, R.compose(R.sum, R.pluck));
```

but this way has not `propOr` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a number of ways you can go about this. Assuming you still want the function curried, the easiest way is to just make add the arguments

```
const sumByPropName = R.curry((prop, items) => R.compose(R.sum, R.map(R.propOr(0, prop)))(items))
```

An alternative is to use `R.defaultTo` to map over the undefined values and set them all to `0`, before passing to `sum`

```
const sumByPropName = R.curryN(2, R.compose(R.sum, R.map(R.defaultTo(0)), R.pluck))
```

Lastly, you could create a `pluckOr` function yourself, keeping `sumByPropName` a bit cleaner (although there's surely a nicer way to write `pluckOr`)

```
const pluckOr = R.curry((defaultVal, propName, items) => R.map(R.propOr(defaultVal, propName), items))
const sumByPropName = R.curryN(2, R.compose(R.sum, pluckOr(0)))
```